# back button browser causes go to home page

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I would like to understand more about how to capture if a user click on the back button of the browser, and what are the basic tecniques to handle it.

As an example of this do you know how to redirect (for instance) to the user to the home page if the back button is pressed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't. Users expect their back button to work in a certain way, changing this breaks this behaviour. Bad, bad.

Comment: Yes, but then how you handle button clicks in the browser on ajax calls to return to previous status?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to document onKeyPress:

```
document.onkeypress = myKeyPressHandler;
// NOTICE: IS NOT a good idea to change the behabiour of backspace  
function myKeyPressHandler() {
    if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 8) {
         // Handle backspace
         // I. E. Go to the home page
         window.home(); // 
    }
}
```

Actually **changing the default beahabiour of backspace is not a good practice** and you should avoid doing it unless you have very good reason or you will confuse your users.

Comment: Sorry pconcepcion, but is about click on the "back button" of the browser.

Comment: I confused your question, sorry.